# GitHub User Page New Themes and Changes Not Updating

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I've been trying to customize my GitHub User page and followed the provided (below) directions precisely.
https://github.com/github/personal-website

The website is running, but I selected the "jekyll-theme-minimal" theme and added the appropriate lines in the "_config.yml" and "index.md" pages. I even copied over the "includes", "layouts", and "assets" folders from the jekyll minimal theme folder itself into my personal website directory. But no updates. Also, I've made a few changes to the website (such as changing the profile photo) but no changes are observed at my personal website below:

https://yjkimnada.github.io

Below is the github directory:

https://github.com/yjkimnada/yjkimnada.github.io

I don't get any errors when running "bundle exec jekyll serve" except:

Inheriting Faraday::Error::ClientError is deprecated; use Faraday::ClientError instead. It will be removed in or after version 1.0
Faraday::Error::ClientError.inherited called from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/octokit-4.14.0/lib/octokit/middleware/follow_redirects.rb:14.

Edit: I do see changes coming up at "http://127.0.0.1:4000" even though they aren't exactly the changes I want. They just seem to be reflecting whatever I write in the index.html file and not the _config.yml file.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to the project's Gemfile

> add gem "jekyll-assets", "~> 2.3.2"

This post was helpful for me.
https://dylanbeattie.net/2019/12/12/shaving-the-jekyll-yak.html